# Sum of independent binomials is binomial

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, convolution

My question is related to the question 
[Sum of Independent Binomials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172671/sum-of-independent-binomials)

How is it possible to sum X from 0 to w? I see two potential problems:

1. Since $X\sim$Binomial(n,p), $X$ can maximally be $n$, and if $w=n+m$, how can then $x$ be $n+m$?
2. If $w> n$, how do we calculate ${n \choose w}$?  This means that $\sum_{x=0}^w{m\choose x}{n\choose w-x}$ does not make sense when $w>n$? There is also a problem if $w>m$, since then ${m\choose x}$ does not make sense when $x=w$.

Based on **1** and **2**, it seems like the proof given in   [Sum of Independent Binomials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172671/sum-of-independent-binomials)
is only correct when $w\leq \min(n,m)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that for two independent binomial variables $X \sim B(n,p)$ and $Y \sim B(m,p)$ and $W=X+Y$, we have

$$P(W = w) = \mathop{ \sum \sum}_{y+x = w} p (y) p(x)$$

and the convolution formula you see on the other post is the next step from here, i.e. put $ y = w - x$ and sum over all values of $x$. That formula might be a little confusing if you forget where it comes from so it's worth keeping the above double sum in mind.

Your question now is about the values of these variables that we sum over. While it is true that $X$ cannot be larger than $n$ and similarly $Y$ cannot be larger than $m$, you are correct here, this does not mean that $w$ needs to be smaller than both $n$ and $m$. The random variable $W$ is the sum of two nonnegative random variables and as such, it can assume all integer values between $0$ and $n+m$.

For each of these integer values we count the combinations of $X$ and $Y$ that yield this value and add their probabilities but we always respect their boundaries while doing so. To give you an example, suppose we are looking for the probability of $P\left( W= n+m \right)$. The only way this can happen is if $X$ and $Y$ assume their maximal values. It makes no sense to compute things like $P(X = n+ 1)$ etc. No, this probability must come from

$$P\left( W= n+m \right) = P\left( X = n \right) P\left( Y = m \right) $$

and only from here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnK. Could you please do some more of the steps, I am still confused. If you always respect the boundaries, how can you sum x from 0 to w?

Comment: @FredikLAa Which steps are you referring to?

Comment: I am still confused about the convolution theorem, @JohnK. Could you please explain how your fomula for calculating P(W=w)(i.e the double sum) is related to the convolution theorem?

Comment: @FredikLAa That is simple actually, put $y = w-x$ and sum over all the values of $x$ and that way you get the convultion formula. This is related to the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: thanks for help, @JohnK, it is very appreciated. When you sum the values of x, you sum from x=0 to x=w. Here is how I think:  $P(X+Y=w)=\sum_{x=0}^n P(X+Y=w,X=x)=\sum_{x=0}^n P(X+Y=w|X=x)P(X=x)=\sum_{x=0}^n P(Y=w-x|X=x)P(X=x)=\sum_{x=0}^n P(Y=w-x)P(X=x)$, where the last equality follows since X and Y are independent. I have here used the law of total probability  in the first equality, and since x can take values from x=0 to x=n, I sum from x=0 to x=n. When you sum over the values of x in your expression, why do you sum from x=0 to x=w?

Comment: But $Y$ is also a random variable, you need to sum over it as well. The convolution will pick all the possible combinations and weigh them by their probabilities. I advise you to read a little bit more about the distribution of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \sim \text{Bin}(m,p)$ and $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$. You want to find the distribution of $W = X + Y$.

Let's ask what that even means. For example, in what circumstances does $W = 2$? It is when $X + Y = 2$, e.g. $X = 1, Y = 1$.

Now is it clear what your confusion is?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @Xodarap. Could you please explain some further? You sum $x$ from $0$ to $ w$, and if $W=w=n+m$, then $X=m, Y=n$.